# Add extra column to existing table populated with datatables

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I am populating a table with datatables. The table has four columns always. But I need to add another column which can be shown or hidden based on boolean value.
My code so far:

```
{% show_extra_fields_button = show_extra_fields_bool %}

<table class="display" id="fields_datatable" class="fields_datatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Place</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Add Extra</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script src="/static/js/vendor/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fields_datatable").dataTable({
      ajax: {
      "processing": true,
      "dataSrc": "",
      url: 'app/personFields/',
      },
      "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "place" },
        { "data": "email" },
        { "data": "phone" },
      ]
    })

    if (show_extra_fields_button) {
      $("#fields_datatable tr").each(function(){
         $(this).append("<td><button>Add Extra</button</td>");
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here I would want to show the `Add Extra` column based on the boolean value. I want the header and the column values which will be buttons to be added using js.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data tables built-in functionality.

To add a button column you can use the following column definition:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "name": "buttonColumn",
    "render": function (data, type, row) {
        return '<button>Add Extra</button>';
    }
}
```

Then use [initComplete](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) callback to set the columns' visibility once table has fully been initialised, data loaded and drawn:

```
$("#fields_datatable").dataTable({
     ajax: {           
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                        
        url: 'app/personFields/',
     },
     "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "place" },
        { "data": "email" },
        { "data": "phone" },
        {
          "data": null,
          "name": "buttonColumn",
          "render": function (data, type, row) {
              return '<button>Add Extra</button>';
           }
        }
     ],
     "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
         // get instance of datatable
         table = settings.oInstance.api();                            
         // get column using its name and set visibility
         table.column('buttonColumn:name').visible(show_extra_fields_button);
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `-` instead of deleting that `<td>` for example `<td>-</td>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the table header just the same way you are adding to the table body.

```
 if (show_extra_fields_button) {

    $('#fields_datatable thead tr').append('<th>Add Extra</th>')

  }
```

Execute it just one time.

Comment: Yes. Got it! Also I had to set `async: false` to the datatable. Is there anyway where I could wait for the datatable to load and then append it?

Comment: the `ajax` can be a function. The second parameter is a callback in which you can maybe append the header.